# jquery nested bind

Tags: jquery, bind

I am very new to jquery and javascript. I am looking at how Splunk implements some of its modules and got confused.

Here is sample code with a lot of stuff left out.

```
this.input.bind("focus",this.onInputFocus.bind(this))
```

this.input refers to a textbox used for a SearchBar. Later, in the file, onInputFocus is declared

```
onInputFocus: function(evt) {
   ...
   ...
   return true
},
```

I know the "this.input.bind" statement tells the browser to execute onInputFocus when a person clicks in the textbox but I do not understand  .bind(this) at the end of the eventhandler. Please explain to me this notation so I understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "outer" [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind) is binding an event handler to the `focus` event using jQuery.

The "inner" `Function.bind` is creating a function that is bound to a particular context (making `this` equal to that context when the function is called). This does not require a framework (but does require a modern browser).

So, in this case, the call to `Function.bind` is making sure that every time `input` is focused, the `onInputFocus` method's context is set to the current value of `this` (which is probably the widget/component you're using). This is necessary because it usually would be the element the event occurred on.

[The MDN article on `Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) has a good explanation of this.

---

To better illustrate how this works, take a simple example:

**HTML:**

```
​<button id="test" type="button">Test</button>
<button id="test2" type="button">Test 2</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var fill = function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
};
/* button#test will be colored yellow */
$("#test").bind("click", fill);

/* div#target will be colored yellow */
$("#test2").bind("click", fill.bind($("#target")));
```

In the first event binding, `fill` is called and `this` is set to `#test` (since that was the element that was clicked).

In the second, `fill` is called again, but `this` is set to `#target` because of the call to `Function.bind` inside of the event binding.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GK7L8/